# VB.Net DataTable.Select - Sort expression syntax

Tags: vb.net, sorting, datatable

I need to select rows from a DataTable and sort them by "Field1 / Field2"

I tried this code:

```
Using DT_Tmp As DataTable = DT.Select("", "FirstNum/SecondNum desc").CopyToDataTable
```

but I get error saying that column "FirstNum/SecondNum" doesn't exist.

EDIT
So far I'm using (as a workaround) a temp table which I'm adding a Field where I store the ratio and I'm using that Field to sort the table.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the select method is smart enough to do calculations on the field.  The other workaround is to add a computed column to your datatable and use that as the sort column

Comment: Here https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/zk13kdh0(v=vs.71).aspx and here https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.71).aspx I've read it's possible

Answer (score 0):

Try putting each column inside brackets

```
Using DT_Tmp As DataTable = DT.Select("", "[FirstNum] / [SecondNum] desc").CopyToDataTable
```

Comment: I can't test it now, I'll make you know if it works as soon as possible

Comment: Sorry, it continues giving the same error, even with brackets

Answer (score 0):

Based on the links you looked at, you need to add the caluculated column first.

```
csortnum= New DataColumn
 With csortnum
     .DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Decimal")
     .ColumnName = "sortcolumn"
     .Expression = "FirstNum/SecondNum"
 End With
DT.add(csortnum)
Using DT_Tmp As DataTable = DT.Select("", csortnum desc").CopyToDataTable
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already using this kind of workaround (haven't you seen my edit?)